# Learning how to structure websites and how to code them

Tags: architecture

I am in the process of creating a (hopefully large) social media website that will kind of be similar in nature to sites like youtube, facebook, twitter. This will be my first endeavor into web development.

I have investigated the tools that highly trafficked sites have used to engineer their sites, and I would like to use the same tools. From my investigation, I believe Python, Apache, and MySQL will be best suited for our website. Web2Py seems like a good opensource python framework that I could possibly use. I hear its similar ruby on rails but for python, which is a good thing.

My question is, are there any up-to-date videos, books, articles, source code, etc that I should look at to learn about the software architecture of websites, and see how larger and highly trafficked sites  structure and code their software?

I do not want to use any opensource CMS's(like drupal) or restricting web frameworks because I don't want my software to restricted in any way in the far future.

I appreciate any feedback.

Edit
ps.Keep in mind I am not looking for basic programming books, I already know how to pick up languages like ruby, python, etc on the fly.
I am more interested in how I should be setting up Architecture of the site(eg. Classes, databases, software) UML graphs would greatly help me as well

Comment: Have you tried searching Amazon or the like for books on the topic? There are probably hundreds.

Comment: I like the fact that you will be building the next TwitFace as your " ... first endeavor into web development." - Good on yer!

Comment: Not to put a damper on your dream of creating the next 'TwitFace' (as @Mitch says, but you might think about something much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting into web development and don't have an extensive programming background I would suggest:

Ruby on Rails or
Python and Django

Python is going to have a more traditional C style syntax which is a bit easier for people who have been programming for a long time to get their head around. But RoR is great.

If you want to learn Ruby on Rails get a www.tekpub.com subscription and they have some great videos on Ruby on Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the previous poster, especially if you are new to web development and do not have extensive programming background, I would recommend that you try [WEB2PY](http://web2py.com/).

It is very well documented and is very, very easy to install and run out of the box with sufficient examples included to put you ahead of the pack.

Yes, you will have to learn Python and yes, that is probably a good thing.

Bear in mind that I am writing this about 9 months after the previous poster gave his answer and I am not sure what was the state of web2py at that time.

Anyway, give it a try.  You will get web2py working faster than either `Django` or `RoR` without a shadow of a doubt.